# Python 3.x Short memory number guessing (Programming/Math)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, recursion

(This could be both a programming problem and a mathematical problem but posting here first.)

I've made a simple program that plays a guessing game between the computer and itself. It generates a number between 0 and 100 inclusive and then gets guesses from another function. The program works but is highly imprecise because the guessing function only knows the last guess and if it should guess higher or lower. (Right now it just randomizes an int between the last guess and the lowest/highest bound.)

The easiest solution would be with `if-else` but I would prefer a solution with as little conditionals as possible.

I wonder if there is a way to make the guessing function gradually narrow the width of its guessing when it only knows its last guess, if it should guess higher or lower and the maximum and minimum bounds of the guess?

Current code:

```
import random as rnd
def guess_me_computer(number = None, guess = 50, turns = 0, memory = []): 
    """Guessing game between two computers.

    Args:
        number: Number to be guessed
        guess: Guess made by computer
        turns: How many guesses made so far
        memory: List storing how many turns each run takes
    """
    turns += 1

    if number == None:
        number = rnd.randint(0, 100)

    if guess == number:
        print("Correct! My number: {number} was guessed in {turns} tries!".format(number = number, turns = turns))
        memory.append(turns) #Memory used in another testing function
        return None
    elif guess < number:
        print("Wrong! Guess Higher!")
        guess_me_computer(number = number, guess = guesser_computer(last_guess = guess, higher = True), turns = turns, memory = memory)
    else:
        print("Wrong! Guess Lower!")
        guess_me_computer(number = number, guess = guesser_computer(last_guess = guess, higher = False), turns = turns, memory = memory)


def guesser_computer(last_guess = None, higher = None):
    if higher:
        return rnd.randint(last_guess, 100)
    else:
        return rnd.randint(0, last_guess)
```

Any and all questions about question itself and/or criticism about the writing are very welcome.

Comment: Hint : handling state is usually done using objects. Also (unrelated but) 1. you would be better using iteration instead of recursion (simpler and more pythonic for this use case) and 2. you don't need the ` global rnd` in your functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 1. I know I should have used a while loop for the guessing and then breaking out when it finishes. This is also for some training in recursion since I have not used it before but enjoy the concept. 2. Removed 'global rnd', thought they had to be used to use rnd in the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a great problem for learning recursion, it could be an interesting problem for learning about generators, particularly their `.send()` method.  The generator below still only knows the last guess made but it also gets a hint from the program invoking it whether that guess was too high or too low:

```
from random import randint

def guess_me_computer(guesser):
    number = randint(1, 100)
    tries = 1
    too_low = None
    guess = next(guesser)

    while True:
        if guess == number:
            print("Number: {} guessed in {} tr{}!".format(number, tries, ["ies", "y"][tries == 1]))
            return

        if guess < number:
            print("Wrong! {} is too low! Guess Higher!".format(guess))
            too_low = True
        else:
            print("Wrong! {} is too high! Guess Lower!".format(guess))
            too_low = False

        tries += 1
        guess = guesser.send(too_low)

def guesser_computer(minimum=1, maximum=100):
    while True:
        guess = randint(minimum, maximum)
        higher = yield guess

        if higher:
            minimum = guess + 1
        else:
            maximum = guess - 1

generator = guesser_computer()
guess_me_computer(generator)
```

Comment: This is very interesting. I have not come far enough in my Python to have learned about generators and '.send()' so thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good exercise to myself so I took a try with binary search. It's interesting. (Inline comments are used as explanation of code.)

```
import random
import numpy as np

max_iters = 10000  #maximum iterations to calculate mean and standard variation of trials
min_num = 0  # a game to guess a random number ranging [0, 100]
max_num = 100
memory = []  # to store the number of turns for each game
numbers_for_guess = [random.randint(min_num, max_num) for i in range(max_iters)]
n_iters = 0  # counter for number of iterations
turns = 0  # counter for number of turns for each game
while n_iters < max_iters:
    # Use binary search
    guess_min = 0  # lower bound for the next guess
    guess_max =  max_num  # upper bound for the next guess
    guess = random.randint(min_num, max_num)  # start from a random number
    while True:
        turns += 1
        if guess == numbers_for_guess[n_iters]:
            memory.append(turns)
            turns = 0
            break
        else:
            if guess > numbers_for_guess[n_iters]:
                guess_max = guess  # narrow down the range for making the next guess
                guess = round((guess + guess_min) / 2, 0)
            else:
                guess_min = guess  # narrow down the range for making the next guess
                guess = round((guess + guess_max) / 2, 0)
    n_iters += 1

print(f'The computer needs {np.mean(memory):.2f} +/- {np.std(memory):.2f} turns to guess the correct number.')
```

This outputs:

```
The computer needs 6.09 +/- 1.48 turns to guess the correct number.
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Amy! This is a solution I would have used if not self-constricted by the short memory I explained in the question. My guessing function only knows what the last guess was and if the next guess should be higher or lower.